# How to search each occurrence in a text file Linux?

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, grep

I have 23 strings to search, I want it returns those that are in the file.

I got the code below:

```
users='User1\|User2\|User3\|User4\|User5\|User6\|User7\|User8\|User9\|User10\|User11\|User12..User23'
```

Desired output:

```
User1 is in the file
User2 is not in the file
...
User 23 is in the file
```

I have no idea how to make it, I was thinking in an array but, I want some tips if is possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
users=( User1 User2 User3 User4 )
for i in "${users[@]}"
do
   grep -qw $i file && echo "$i is in the file" || echo "$i is not in the file"
done
```

From `man`:

> -q, --quiet, --silent
>
> Quiet; do not write anything to standard output.  Exit immediately with zero status if any match is found, even if an error was detected.

Comment: Change that for loop index from `$i` to just `i`, and also quote the array `"${users[@]}"` OTW liable to have issues with  variable expansion. Plus the `grep` can be made more robust by invoking it with `-w` option to prevent `grep` from selecting user11 when it really was looking for user1.

Answer (score 4):

Use an array:

```
users=(User1 User2 User3 User4) # et cetera
for i in "${users[@]}"; do
    echo -n "$user is "
    if grep -q "$user" inputfile; then
        echo "present"
    else
        echo "not present"
    fi
done
```

`grep -q` will execute the search but not return any output, allowing you to use it silently in an `if` test.

Alternatively, you can put each user on its on line in a file called `Users`, and then:

```
grep -o -f Users inputfile
```

This will output a list of all users seen.  If you want to see both present and absent users, you could:

```
echo "Users present:"
grep -o -f Users inputfile
echo "Users absent:"
grep -vo -f Users inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

A further tweak.

```
users=( User1 User2 User3 User4 )
for i in "${users[@]}"
do
   echo "$i is" $(grep -qw $i file || echo "not") "in the file"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

With only a single scan through the file: this is bash

```
# the array of user names
users=( User{1..23} )
# an array of grep options: ( -e User1 -e User2 ...)
for u in "${users[@]}"; do grep_opts+=( -e "$u" ); done
# scan the input file and save the user names that are present in the file
readarray -t users_present < <(grep -Fo "${grep_opts[@]}" input | sort -u)
# find the user names absent from the file
# this assumes there are no spaces in any of the user names.
for u in "${users[@]}"; do
     [[ " ${users_present[*]} " == *" $u "* ]] || users_absent+=( "$u" )
done
# and print out the results
printf "%s is in the file\n" "${users_present[@]}"
printf "%s is NOT in the file\n" "${users_absent[@]}"
```